# Alternate Access Mapping help

Tags: 2007, alternate-access-mapping

I have a site on port 8080, and extended the site to port 80. Then I added an alternate access mapping to the new url on port 80. I have also created a new host file entry and added the host entry name to the host header configuration in IIS for the extended web app.

If I browse to the site on port 8080, I can access the site with no problems. I can also access the site on port 80 with no problems.

When I try to access the site using the newly created host entry, I get a error that the page cannot be displayed.

The setup:

Server 2003 Standard edition (x64)
Sql Server 2005 Standard

- original url - `http://jason-1541466b8:8080/sites/denver/default.aspx`
- extended url - `http://jason-1541466b8/sites/denver/default.aspx`
- host entry - mynewsharepoint
- updated url - `http://mynewsharepoint/sites/denver/default.aspx`

Alternate Access Mappings

- default - `http://jason-1541466b8:8080`
- intranet - `http://jason-1541466b8`
- custom - `http://mynewsharepoint`

I think I am missing a minor detail somewhere, but cannot seem to find it.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: I just noticed the environment setup - are you getting prompted for authentication when trying to access the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open IIS and add http://mynewsharepoint to the list of host-header bindings being listened to by your SharePoint site

Comment: turns out there were some server settings that were causing the issue

Comment: which server settings besides the ones mentioned by the answerer?